# Reading a properties file in linux

Tags: linux, bash, sh

I want to be able to read a properties file in linux, check for if certain properties exist. If the properties I am looking for exist but they dont match the value I am looking for I want to override those respective properties. If they dont exist then I want to write them to the file.

Can any linux guru help me out with this.

Thanks in advance!

Also the key names can be in the form pre1.pre2.pre3
so something like
pre1.pre2.pre3 = value

The following is the properties file

```
net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6 = 1
net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6 = 1
kernel.sysrq = 0
net.ipv4.ip_forward = 0
net.ipv4.tcp_syncookies = 1
net.ipv6.conf.all.forwarding = 0
net.ipv4.tcp_keepalive_time = 30
net.ipv4.tcp_keepalive_intvl = 5
net.ipv4.tcp_keepalive_probes = 5
```

I want to change all the settings for tcp basically.

Comment: What is a properties file and how does it look like?

Comment: @SzG http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.properties

Comment: Included the properties file in my question. Basically I want to override properties in /etc/sysctl.conf through a script basically so they are preserved on system reboot.

Comment: What about editing the file? `sudo nano /etc/sysctl.conf`

Comment: Cant do that. need a script to automate the process.

Comment: Yes, but how often do the values change? Where are the new values coming from?

Comment: Thanks for the response. But I actually need a script. I wouldnt have asked if I thought the stuff could have been modified manually.

Comment: I'm bit curious. You want a script to set these system variables (which are normally set via sysctl or sysctl.conf during startup, as mentioned above). And if i'm not mistaken, you need root privileges to set these. So why do these need to be set via script ? If you need such nonstandard solution, there needs to be a reason.

Comment: how do i set them via a sysctl so that it preserves across system reboots? as far as I understood, if I want it to be preserved across reboots, I need to modify the sysctl.conf file but since its on a client machine that I have no control over and the client is not an avid linux user I have to modify the process.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are some steps that you might find useful for your script:

- does foo.bar exist in a.properties?

`if grep foo.bar a.properties ; then echo found ; else echo not found; fi`

-> `if` tests the outcome of `grep`

- replace the property with it's new value

`cat a.properties | sed '/foo.bar/c\foo.bar = the new value'`

-> `sed` with the c command changes a whole line

Looks like the last command is all you need :)

ps: I love these 'avoid bash' discussions :)

Comment: I just ran this
cat a.properties | sed '/foo.bar/c\foo.bar = the new value' > a.properties but it just emptied the file. Prior a.properties had a foo.bar = 12 in it

Comment: don't redirect while still playing with your commands - too dangerous.

Comment: ok i dont get what you mean by above. i am using bash for the first time. what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/sh
ensure_value() {
    file="$1"
    property="$2"
    value="$3"
    if ! grep -q "$property" "$file"; then
        echo $property = $value >> "$file"
    else
        sed -i -e "s/^$property.*/$property = $value/g" "$file"
    fi
}

# cp props props.$(date +%s).bak
ensure_value props net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6 1
ensure_value props net.ipv4.ip_forward 1
# etc.
```

This script is not safe or production-ready! Note that the function `ensure_value` evaluates regexs in property names and it can go horribly wrong if your property ends up being something like `.*`. Really, you should use [Ansible's INI file module](http://docs.ansible.com/ini_file_module.html) or similar instead.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I'd like to point out that modifying properties files via scripts can be quite dangerous so please be careful when you are testing this.  I can think of two options that would get you what you want.

1. If you want just a defaults file which won't change and simply want to replace what you have with a defaulted file, then you can keep a default version of the file on hand and do a simple diff between the properties file and your default version.  If the files differ, copy the default to the actual file.
2. Since I suspect that option 1 is not viable for you, I would look into doing sed replacements in the file.  There are plenty of tutorials on how to edit files with sed out there on the internet.

Hope this helps.